# Relay data ambiguity

Tags: relay, coil, contact

I found a relay with some characteristics written on it.
The coil should be powered at 12VDC.
The other data is unclear.

IEC 255 3A 150VAC

5A 240VAC - AC1

5A 28VDC -DC1

So, in AC, the contacts should work at **5A 240VAC - AC1**.

What is the meaning of **3A 150VAC** vs **5A 240VAC - AC1**?
 Shouldn't I be able to run 5A 150VAC through my relay?

Comment: So, have you tried to google it? It comes up with answers and you should really do some background work first before asking here hence I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of lack of really simple google research.

Comment: Of course i googled it. But, apart from some datasheets, i found no explanation.

Comment: I mean, in AC, it should work at 3A and 150VAC or 5A and 240VAC?

Comment: Well I googled "IEC 255" and the first five hits established it was referring to an IEC standard so no, I don't accept your laziness.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different standards use different load conditions (load inductance, temperature), and different definitions of 'end of life' (contact resistance change or total failure). So you would expect different limiting use conditions depending on what standard it's tested to. Look up IEC255 and see what the conditions are.

In the solid state Tesla coiling community, a common user standard is 'turn it up until it explodes, then back off a bit', which results in higher use currents than the boring old data sheet tends to suggest. I wouldn't propose that standard for, say, safety critical flight electronics.